# select last row after various aggregation functions

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
select  b.Project_Id,b.Id,
FIRST_VALUE(i.Number) OVER(PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY i.Date) as FirstNumDDT
,sum( ir.Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY i.date)  as sumqty
from InvoiceRow ir 
inner join Invoice i on i.id=Invoice_Id 
inner join BillOfMaterial b on b.id=ir.BOM_Id
```

and a few part of the result is:

| Project_Id | Id | FirstNumDDT | sumqty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16088 | 1986620 | 21803 | 1 |
| 16088 | 1986620 | 21803 | 4 |

I need only the last row. How can I filter?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TOP(N)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) in combination with an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
       b.Project_Id,b.Id,
       FIRST_VALUE(i.Number) OVER(PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY i.Date) as FirstNumDDT,
       SUM(ir.Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY i.date)  as sumqty
from InvoiceRow ir 
INNER JOIN Invoice i on i.id=Invoice_Id 
INNER JOIN BillOfMaterial b on b.id=ir.BOM_Id
ORDER BY sumqty DESC
```

If you want allow to retrieve all values that have the maximum sumqty values, you need to use `TOP(1) WITH TIES` instead.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
       b.Project_Id,b.Id,
       FIRST_VALUE(i.Number) OVER(PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY i.Date) as FirstNumDDT,
       SUM(ir.Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY i.date)  as sumqty
from InvoiceRow ir 
INNER JOIN Invoice i on i.id=Invoice_Id 
INNER JOIN BillOfMaterial b on b.id=ir.BOM_Id
ORDER BY sumqty DESC
```